# How many m length unique strings can you make from an n length list of unique characters

Tags: math

Imagine a list of characters of length n, no character is duplicated.  Using a mathematical formula, how can you find the number of unique m length strings that can be made from that list of characters?

Comment: `"mathematical formula"` -> probably belongs on [math.se].

Comment: The tag editor says it's the same thing

Comment: Sounds like elementary [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Comment: Thanks Dukeling, I thought of the Lehmer code first too, but it doesn't take into account the variable length of the results (m)

Comment: Thanks Brett.  Do you want to put that in an answer so I can vote on it.

Comment: I've just found this in "In combinatorics" on the wiki page you linked Dukeling.  It's just the language they employ is a little overwhelming for me and I found it difficult to pick out what I was looking for.

Once again, thanks very much Brett!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation): `n!/((n - m)!)` - different orderings, no repetitions.

`(n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * ... * 1)` divided by `((n - m) * (n - m - 1) * (n - m - 2) * ... * 1)`. the '**!**' is [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) notation.